# child components selector messing up parent div row

Tags: angular

Just learning Angular and want to do this:

```
<div class="row">

<app-kid name="kid one"></app-kid>
<app-kid name="kid two"></app-kid>
</div>
```

It was supposed to display horizontally but because the DOM includes <div><app-kid>..., it displays vertically one after one.

app-kid.component.html

```
<div class="col-md-5 mt-3 col-lg-3">
    content
</div>
```

app-kid.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-kid',
  templateUrl: './kid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./kid.component.css']
})
export class KidComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() name = "";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

how do I avoid app-kid from being inserted into the DOM tree.

I tried pasting kid compnoent code into my parent component and it worked but i want to separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting the `col` class in your first div, put it in your .ts file like this:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-kid',
   templateUrl: './kid.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./kid.component.css'],
   host: {'class': 'someClass1'}
})
```

This way, the attribute class will be applied to `<app-kid>` - which is a **host** of the app-kid component